# How can I sort an object in a list?

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following code

```
class Tupla:
       def __init__(self, xid, prob):
           self.xid = xid
           self.prob = prob
```

and I append to a list some objects of this class

```
print myList1
>> [('X10', 11, ''), ('X9', 11, ''), ('X11', 11, ''), ('X2', 11, '')]
```

I try to order it

```
myList1 = sorted(myList1, key=lambda Tupla: Tupla.xid, reverse=True)

print myList1
>> [('X9', 11, ''), ('X2', 11, ''), ('X11', 11, ''), ('X10', 11, '')]
```

I am looking for human sorting. I need order the list like this:

```
 [('X2', 11, ''), ('X9', 11, ''), ('X10', 11, ''), ('X11', 11, '')]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
def Tupla(xid, prob):
    class _Tupla:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def get_id(self):
            return xid

        def get_prob(self):
            return prob


    return _Tupla()

myList = map(lambda arg: Tupla(*arg), (('X10', 11), ('X9', 11), ('X11', 11), ('X2', 11)))
myList.sort(key = lambda obj: int(obj.get_id()[1:]))

print [(x.get_id(), x.get_prob()) for x in myList]
```

**Output:**

```
[('X2', 11), ('X9', 11), ('X10', 11), ('X11', 11)]
```

Comment: ¬¬ i doing that sorted(myList1, key=lambda Tupla: Tupla.xid, reverse=True) do you read the question?? i only need that sort like human sorting